# How does a miner choose which transactions go into the next block?

Tags: transaction-selection

How does a miner choose which transactions go into the next block?
Do all transactions go through or is there a lottery process? I understand transactions with higher fees are given priority.

Answer (score 3):

A miner can choose whichever (valid) transactions they’d like to include in a block, for any reason they’d like.

> I understand transactions with higher fees are given priority.

Generally, yes, we would assume a rational miner would maximize the amount of fees they can possibly obtain. But this is not mandatory.